# I would like to know the setting to change the div to the vertical and horizontal center

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an interface of type test, and I'm asking about a div.

[html]

```
<body>
    <div class="top_header">
        <div class="top_header_logo">test</div>
        <div class="top_header_product">test</div>
        <div class="top_header_manual">test</div>
</body>
```

[css]

```
body {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
}

.top_header {
    border: 1px solid gainsboro;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.top_header_logo {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 70px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    /* margin-top: 20px; */
    font-family: 'Bungee', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.top_header_product {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 70px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align :center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-family: 'Bungee', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.top_header_product:hover {
    color: cornflowerblue;
}

.top_header_manual {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 70px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-family: 'Bungee', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.top_header_empty {
    width: 17%;
    float: left;
    height: 70px;    
}
```

I want the 3 tests to be centered horizontally and vertically to match the size of the parent. I tried text-align/flex and it didn't give me good results. Do you have any feedback?

Comment: If you mean    `.top_header`    as parent, then you need to add some height to it like    `height: 100vh;`    . You will see that tests are already vertically centered. Now add     `justify-content: center;`    to align horizontally middle.

Comment: As you said, add height: 100vh to the parent class; justify-content: center; Even if you gave the option, the resulting value didn't change. However, after several attempts, I can also think of using padding to move the text value to the center, is there any problem with this?

Comment: There is a problem because different devices have different height. With due respect, you may missed something. You can also see the code snippet preview in answer provided by sumeshsn1. That works completely fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `justify-content: center;` to `.top_header` also no need for `float:left` since flex items will be auto-aligned to each other. Also to see the vertical alignment `flex-items` visually you need to add a specific height for your flexbox, which is `top_header`.

```css
body {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
}

.top_header {
    border: 1px solid gainsboro;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.top_header_logo {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 20%;
    height: 70px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Bungee', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.top_header_product {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 20%;
    height: 70px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align :center;
    font-family: 'Bungee', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.top_header_product:hover {
    color: cornflowerblue;
}

.top_header_manual {
    width: 20%;
    height: 70px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Bungee', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.top_header_empty {
    width: 17%;
    float: left;
    height: 70px;    
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="top_header">
        <div class="top_header_logo">test</div>
        <div class="top_header_product">test</div>
        <div class="top_header_manual">test</div>
    </div>
</body>
```